# Pick values from multiple cells and paste output in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-concatenation, textjoin

I have a dataset which looks like:

```
A   0.998315185
B   0.232720507
C   0.010558964
D   0.004246209
E   0.002552556
```

I want to paste below output in one cell as:

```
0.998315185A+0.232720507B+0.010558964C+0.004246209D+0.002552556E
```

So that I can copy this and use it elsewhere.

Comment: Why you only use capital letter?

Comment: HI ROY. Please edit your question to remove the SHOUTY capital letters.

Comment: How big is your sample? If it's only a few cells, you can manually concatenate with the ampersand (&):
`=A2&"A +"&A3&"B +"`
etc.

Comment: sample is of 40 rows

Comment: are you taking about mainframe dataset?

Comment: Google Sheets is very useful in such a case. Just one formula `=join("+", arrayFormula(filter(B:B&A:A, B:B&A:A <> "")))` is enough. Why not use Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this User Defined Function. Use this function in a cell on the sheet like this...

```
=CombineData(A1:B5)
```

**User Defined Function:**

```
Function CombineData(ByVal Rng As Range) As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim str As String
Dim cell As Range
For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
    For j = Rng.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If str = "" Then
            str = Rng.Cells(i, j)
        Else
            str = str & Rng.Cells(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
    str = str & "+"
Next i
CombineData = str
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the newer TEXTJOIN function as an **array formula** with CSE.

```
=TEXTJOIN("+", TRUE, B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B))&A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))
```

[image]

---

¹ <sub>The [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) was introduced with Excel 2016 in the following versions:*Excel for Android phones, Excel Mobile, Excel 2016 with Office 365, Excel 2016 for Mac, Excel Online, Excel for iPad, Excel for iPhone and Excel for Android tablet.*</sub>